# How to keep layer style/symbology when saving as KML?

Tags: qgis, kml, style

When saving as a kml, is it possible to keep the style of the QGIS layer?  I have tried a couple plugins that have been mentioned on here: qgis2kml ('format not yet supported') and qgis2google2 (crashed QGIS upon activating). Is there anything else?

Answer (score 1):

qgis2kml should do what you want.

I get the same error message as you. You should contact the author to let him explain a bit more which data sources he regards as valid input formats.

Comment: Why am I not able to find this plugin? I'm looking in the Plugin menu from the top bar. Downloaded source from github but don't know how to feed it into qgis

Comment: The question was from January, when QGIS 1.8 was current. If noone updated it, the plugin will not be available in QGIS 2.0. If you need it, you can still install older standalone versions of QGIS. But you might get error messages if you downgrade QGIS (upgrading is no problem).

Comment: *would* qgis2kml be able to transpose the color values of individual polygons from qgis's rendering to the kml version? I have a heatmap generated with qgis and want to transpose it to kml to view in google earth